# Mysql get user list of every week interval

Tags: mysql

I want to write query to fetch user from table who register before week interval.
For ex. todays date is 2017-08-17, then I need user who register on 2017-08-10, 2017-08-03,2017-07-27 and so on. Like this if todays date is 2017-08-20 then user will be register on  2017-08-13, 2017-08-06.

```
id name date
1 ABC 2018-08-16
2 PQR 2018-08-10
3 LMN 2018-07-27
4 AAA 2018-01-01
```

Output will be

```
id name date
2 PQR 2018-08-10
3 LMN 2018-07-27
```

Comment: They will have the same weekday value, so it will be something like "select * from users where weekday(register) = weekday(input_date);"

Comment: as per requirement it should work through mysql query.

Comment: what does the source data look like?

Comment: @verhie interval may be in terms of days, week, month,year

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want last weeks registrations, last months registrations and last years registrations? This looks like you want them from 7 days ago, not between 7 and 0 days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to express this problem is to recognize that we want to retain dates whose difference from today are multiple of 7 days.  We can compare the UNIX timestamps of each record and check to see if the number of seconds, when divided by the number of seconds in 7 days, is zero.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) -
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(reg_date)), 7*24*60*60) = 0
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: and if interval is 15 days

Comment: @lbmgplus Then just check for `15*24*60*60`

Comment: interval may be in terms of days, week, month,year. i.e. month. if today 2017-08-17 then result will be  2017-07-17, 2017-06-17

Comment: @lbmgplus What happens with January 31?  February does not have 31 days.  I doubt you really have such a requirement and in any case you are changing your question.  This could draw downvotes.

Comment: Thanks bro. assumed 1month as 30day. Could you please kindly edit my question and make proper it. so this question clear to other.

Comment: Your question is clear for the answer I gave you.  If you want intervals other than 7 days just change the interval in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: If we want to pass two date. In above sql we match current date. if we want match from_date('2017-08-17') and to_date('2017-08-25'). get which date match between this date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE WEEKDAY(`date`) = WEEKDAY(NOW());
```

This will get you all users that registered 0, 7, 14, 21 etc. days ago.

Comment: interval may be in terms of days, week, month,year i.e 15day

Comment: This won't work because months have uneven number of days, and do not have an even 7 day grouping, except for February in a non leap year.